# Effective Terraform Workflow: GitHub Action

Tags: terraform, yaml, github-actions

Currently, my Terraform structure is organized into stacks. This setup utilizes a GitHub Workflow for deployment. Each time I need to deploy to an environment, I must execute to workflow each time for a different command (Plan/Apply) for each stack. While this solution functions, it has required me to run the workflow 8 times for each deployment to an environment.

I aim for the stacks to proceed sequentially after a successful terraform plan, but I also desire an approval stage inbetween the plan and apply commands, for example:

1. Terraform Plan
2. Review the plan and approve, which will initiate the next stage.
3. Terraform Apply
4. Upon successful completion, proceed to the next stack

Is there a way to add a workflow approval in between a job once the Terraform plan has been reviewed?

Answer (score 0):

In gitHub action you could use [Reviewing deployments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments) to approve or reject jobs awaiting review.

Then maybe you could use the conditional **[needs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds)** to concatenate the stack

> Jobs that reference an environment configured with required reviewers will wait for an approval before starting. While a job is awaiting approval, it has a status of "Waiting". If a job is not approved within 30 days, it will automatically fail.

Im not sure what kind of plan you have, but check the **Who can use this feature** for plan limitation, unlike Jenkins or other similar CI/CD solutions, you could find limitations.